# Can Python sorting with a key pass me the ordinal position of the item in the original list, instead of the item itself

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of items I need to sort but the the value I want used in the sort for each item is not in the list itself. The sorting information is in another list, which positionally aligns with the first one.

Ie., l = list of items to sort, v = list of values to use for sorting. When sorting l[0], the value in v[0] should be used.

So during the sort, I need python to tell me the ordinal position of the item being sorted, instead of giving the item itself.

So effectively what I would do is this:

```
l = sort(key = lambda index_of_item: v[index_of_item])
```

By default I think that this would not work as python is invoking that lambda with an actual item from l, not the item's position. Is there a way to have python give me the position instead?

(If there were some identifier in each item being sorted I could use that myself inside the lambda to extrapolate the index_of_item, but sadly there isn't)

Comment: `list.index()` or `enumerate()` should be viable for this

Comment: can you show a few test cases? an example input and output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your list of items to a list of tuples that includes the original index; this can be done using `enumerate()`. Then you can use that index to access the other list.

```
augumented_list = list(enumerate(l))
augmented_list.sort(key = lambda item: v[item[0]])
result = [x[1] for x in augmented_list]
```

Another option is to use `zip()` to combine the elements of both lists, then use the value from the other list as the sort key.

```
result = [x[0] for x in sorted(zip(l, v), key = lambda x: x[1])]
```

Comment: As long as you're relying on `enumerate`, you may as well use `sorted` to combine the `list`ification and sorting into one step: `augmented_list = sorted(enumerate(l), key=lambda item: v[item[0]])`

Comment: Yeah, I just thought it would be clearer to show all the steps separately. I combined everything in my second solution.

Comment: enumerate was the answer, but it's a bit ugly is you have to "get rid of" the  enumeration ordinals after sorting. It would  be great if python would somehow optionally pass the index of the item, allowing for an extra level of indirection

Comment: IMHO Implementing that is tricky, since it would have to remember the original indexes as it's swapping the positions of items. Since this is rarely needed, it would be a performance overhead with little value. I can't think of any other language with a sorting function that provides that ability.

Comment: So it's better off done in the caller in the rare cases where it's needed.

Comment: The fact that you have two separate lists for related data suggests poor data structures in the first place. combine them into a list of tuples or dictionaries.

Comment: @MichaelRayLovett: If you really hate it, a "clever" way to do this, that I ***strongly discourage***, would be to rely on the fact that it generates the keys for each element in order. So you could do without manual decoration by doing: `l.sort(key=lambda _, it=iter(v): next(it))`. Works on the original `l` with no manual decoration (`key` arguments implicitly decorate, sort and undecorate, but you don't have to do it yourself). TO BE CLEAR, THIS IS A TERRIBLE IDEA! Nothing officially *requires* generating the keys in order, it's just the natural way to do it.